# Reading lines from 2 dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to read from 2 dimensional arrays. 
What this code does is that it first stores .txt file contents into 2d arrays, one line per element. It then compares user input to each array, looking for similarities. Any similarity will be stored in another array.

The thing here is that the comparing part doesn't work. Any hints as to why?

Thanks.

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    static int RowCheck =0;
    static int C_Row = 0;
    static int S_Row = 0;


    static String lexicon[][] = new String[3000][10];
    static String results[][] = new String[100][10];


    private static String find2DIndex(Object[][] array, Object search) {

        if (search == null || array == null) return null;

        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < array.length; rowIndex++ ) {
           Object[] row = array[rowIndex];
           if (row != null) {
              for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < 2; columnIndex++) {
                 if (search.equals(row[columnIndex])) {

                     for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
                          for(int j=0; j<=10; j++)
                            lexicon[i][j]=results[i][j];

                         return Arrays.deepToString(results);
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        return null; // value not found in array
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

        File testlex = new File("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\testlex.txt");
        File testlex2 = new File("C:\\Users\\Harry\\Documents\\textlex2.txt");


        Scanner cc = new Scanner(testlex2);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(testlex);

        while (sc.hasNextLine()){
            int column = 0;
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            sc.useDelimiter("/ *");
            if (line.isEmpty())
                continue;

            C_Row = C_Row + 1;
            column = 0;

            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");

            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.isEmpty())
                    continue;
                lexicon[C_Row][column] = token;  
                column++; 
            }
        }

        while (cc.hasNextLine()){
            int column = 0;
            String line = cc.nextLine();
            cc.useDelimiter("/ *");
            if (line.isEmpty())
                continue;

            S_Row = S_Row + 1;
            column = 0;
            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s");
            for (String token : tokens) {
                if (token.isEmpty())
                    continue;

                lexicon[S_Row][column] = token;  
                column++; 
            }
        }

        sc.close();
        cc.close();

        find2DIndex(lexicon, "abash");
        System.out.println(C_Row);

     }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will compare `search` and `row[columnIndex]` as objects of type `Object`.

```
if (search.equals(row[columnIndex]))
```

Therefore it will compare references. You seem to want to compare contents of `String` objects. There are 2 ways you can modify `find2DIndex` for this.

1. Change the signature to

   ```
   private static String find2DIndex(String[][] array, String search)
   ```

   and replace any occurrence of `Object` in the function with `String`
2. Turn it into a generic method

   ```
   private static <T> String find2DIndex(T[][] array, T search)
   ```

   and replace any occurrence of `Object` in the function with `T`

In both cases `equals` will now be the method of `String`.